# Reading an article that takes the cross product of a vector and time.

Tags: calculus

I have this equation in the form:

$$V(t)=ϕV(t−1)+r×t+c+\epsilon $$

Why is $r$ crossed with $t$. The variable $t$, in the article (shown below) is time which I believe is a scalar. I suppose time could be a vector of the form $[t,0,0]$, but I am not sure. I think this is illegal. See for yourself(section 2.1):

http://rsos.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/2/9/150288

I would really like to hear from the community about this.

Comment: I think they're just using the $\times$ symbol to refer to multiplication, for example see formula (3.1).